# Error The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android-studio

I wrote this code RecyclerAdapter for my recyclerView in a fragment. I tried to change the background color of cards in recyclerView randomly by passing an Array of color strings to `holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor())` This code worked and the colors changed randomly but then after few seconds the app crashed and threw the following error in the logcat

```
Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Here's my **RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

String[] postText;
String[] groupName;
String[] backColor = {"#ff6347", "#c2571a", "#a3b86c", "#3c6478", "#EBC94"};

public RecyclerAdapter(String[] postText, String[] groupName){
    this.postText = postText;
    this.groupName = groupName;
}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.txPost.setText(postText[position]);
    holder.txGroupName.setText(groupName[position]);
    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backColor[position]));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return postText.length;
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txPost;
    TextView txGroupName;
    CardView cardView;
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        txPost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_text);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        txGroupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_name);

    }
}
}
```

Why is this error occurring? And how can I fix it. Little bit of explanation will be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can think of is the `Color.parseColor` which may be unnecessarily taking too long to find the color from your color code. Try parsing all the colors on creation of the adapter and see if it works.